# No existe el método AddObject() en Entity Framework Versión 6.0.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy intentando guardar un nuevo objeto en la base de datos con Entity Framework pero no me trae el metodo `AddObject()`. ¿Qué debería hacer? ¿Agregar una nueva referencia?.

```
using(VeterinariaNuevaEntities vetN = new VeterinariaNuevaEntities())
{
    vetN.Dueño.AddObject(objeto);
    return vetN.SaveChanges();
}
```

Y me tira este error:

```
'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' no contiene una definición de 'AddObject' ni se encontró ningún
método de extensión 'AddObject' que acepte un primer argumento de tipo 
'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' (¿falta una directiva de uso o referencia de ensamblado?)
```

Como plataforma de desarrollo uso Visual Studio 2012 y SQL.

Comment: Hola Braian. Por favor, cambia el codigo y el error dejando un texto en vez de una imagen. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El nombre correcto del método es [`.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
using(var vetN = new VeterinariaNuevaEntities())
{
    vetN.Dueño.Add(objeto);
    return vetN.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tambien puedes usar este patrón para insertar o actualizar el registro en caso de que estes usando una propiedad id como llave primaria :

```
using (var vetN = new VeterinariaNuevaEntities()) 
{ 
    vetN .Entry(objeto).State = objeto.Id == 0 ? 
                               EntityState.Added : 
                               EntityState.Modified; 

    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Por supuesto que tienes que cambiar objeto.Id por el nombre de tu propiedad que usas como llave primaria.